# Azure AD B2C and organizational groups

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Consider the following case, for my application:

- I have a website
- The website sits on top of an azure api and gets data from cosmos DB
- The data from cosmos DB is specific for different organizations
- Different organizations should be able to have an "admin" appointed by me
- The organization "admin" should be able to add his colleagues under the same organization
- The users within a particular organization should only be able to view the data specific to their organization

Considering the above use-case, I have thought about using Azure B2C because:

1. Everything is already inside azure
2. I don't want to do security myself

However, I am unsure, if it is actually possible to achieve this with azure B2C? I can't seem to find any similar use-cases in the AD documentation. Hence why I start to think, that I'm going in a wrong direction...?

Therefore, can Azure AD B2C offer, what I want to achieve? (do I need a tenant for each Organization)
In case, Azure AD does not offer support for my use-case, what would you then recommend me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a white-label service, Azure AD B2C cannot be used as a built-in security provider for other Azure services without writing custom code to translate whatever authorization model you maintain in Azure AD B2C into access patterns for CosmosDB or other Azure services.

CosmosDB does have it's own in-built notion of users and permissions which you might map in some way (using custom code) to Azure AD B2C users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#users

You could also use CosmosDB's integration with Azure AD (not B2C) for RBAC controls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control

Finally, Azure AD B2C does not provide any out-of-the-box administrative tooling for the kind of delegated user administration model you described. Again this would need to be a custom coded admin UI or you'd need to use a third-party solution such as Saviynt for delegated administration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/partner-saviynt